# near "WHERE": syntax error - SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, android-sqlite

I have a method that will if check two text fields exist then retune the record ID. 
My method look like this:

```
int getQueryMatch(String word, String meter) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY + " WHERE " + QUERYWORD +  "= '" + word + "' AND WHERE " + DISTANCEQ + "= '"+ meter +"' "  ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int getidd = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID) ;


    Log.v("Match query ", "return? " + getidd );
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // return History
    return getidd;
}
```

and I have my table looks like this:

```
    String CREATE_HISTORYS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_HISTORY + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            QUERYWORD + " TEXT," + DISTANCEQ + " TEXT" + ","  + KEY_TIMESTAMP + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_HISTORYS_TABLE);
```

now when I run the method as if getQueryMatch(Mystr1 , Mystr2);

I got this error:

```
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736): Caused by: ****android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT *  FROM history WHERE query= 'Information Pillar' AND WHERE distance= '20'****
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at com.example.phooogle.DatabaseHandler.getQueryMatch(DatabaseHandler.java:149)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at com.example.phooogle.GoogleMapsAppActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(GoogleMapsAppActivity.java:233)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at com.example.phooogle.GoogleMapsAppActivity$InitTask.doInBackground(GoogleMapsAppActivity.java:1)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-18 22:04:04.294: E/AndroidRuntime(13736):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

My select query looks like alright to me but I don't know what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 WHERE clauses in your query. You are only allowed to have one. Combine them like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY + " WHERE " + QUERYWORD +  "= '" + word + "' AND " + DISTANCEQ + "= '"+ meter +"' "  ;
```

So now you query would be:

```
SELECT *  FROM history WHERE query= 'Information Pillar' AND distance= '20'`
```

This is now valid.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the second `WHERE`, then it will work.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY + " WHERE " + QUERYWORD +  "= '" + word + "' AND WHERE " + DISTANCEQ + "= '"+ meter +"' "  ;
                                                                                                        ^^^^^
                                                                                                   here's the error
```

Ah, and by the way: You query building seems highly vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)! Better fix that.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response it works like a charm ! and I'll have a look on that. Because this the only way I found to do so.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `WHERE` second time after `AND`
Use this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY + " WHERE " + QUERYWORD +  "= '" + word + "' AND " + DISTANCEQ + "= '"+ meter +"' "  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using 2 WHERE Statements; however, this is not allowed, you have to remove the last WHERE statement, since you already have an AND statement.